# VueJS pass data from Ajax request from parent to child as props

Tags: ajax, vue.js

I have a parent component that doing using axios to access URL to fetch data.
I want to pass this data to child component that the child will use this data in rendering.

For Example:
Parent is a list contant, and child is a single contact in the list.
I want the child to use the "person name" props passed to it. and display in inside p tag.

Now that I am trying to do so: the child is rendered before the data gets to the parent from the ajax request and I get errors from child component.
My solution for now is to use SetTimeOut in the mounted function of child.
I am looking for better solution and do the best practice

Thanks Alon

Comment: can you provide an example?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are trying to use the `props` passed from the parent to the child and the child throws errors.

There are a couple of things you can do

- add checks in the child to see if the props are populated or not
- use a `v-if` in the parent. The variable you are using is initially set to `false` and after you get a response from the server you set it to `true`. This way the child is rendered only after you have a response.